# vb.net - Deleting selected List view Item from ini file

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, ini

What I want to do:
I have an ini File which I use as an "index" of jar files. The Jars are declared in it like:
Name of the jar=c:\Path

So when my application starts, the ini file gets loaded in a list view.

And now my Problem. I have a delete button, with which I want to delete the jars from the list view and the ini file.

It must be possible to delete multi choiced jar references. so I thought to do it with for each, so that every selected item get searched in the ini and deleted

The Error is, that the String (is correct, I tested it with a messagebox) get analysed - Unknown escape sequence \ R (The error is betwen the ** **)

My Code:

```
Private Sub jarDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles jarDelete.Click
    If Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            ListView1.Items.Remove(item)

            Dim GanzeZeile As String = ListView1.SelectedItems.ToString
            Dim Sucheninini As String
            Dim inipath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\Mauncher\jars.ini"
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(inipath)
            Dim sw As StreamWriter
            Dim inicontent As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            sr.Close()

            MessageBox.Show(GanzeZeile & ", " & inipath & ", " & item.Text & "=" & item.SubItems.Item(1).Text)

            Sucheninini = item.Text & "=" & item.SubItems.Item(1).Text             
            **inicontent = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inicontent, Sucheninini, "")**
            sw = New StreamWriter(inipath)
            sw.Write(inicontent)
            sw.Close()
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
inicontent = inicontent.Replace(Sucheninini, String.Empty)
```